# Use text quicklook viewer for other files

Tags: macos, quicklook

Is there a way to tell OS X to use the quicklook text viewer for files with specific extensions?

For example, I use emacs [org-mode](http://orgmode.org) for tasks lists, etc. Usually I view (and edit) these in emacs, however sometimes I browse in Finder and want to know the contents of an org file.

Similarly, this would be helpful for .conf files.

I know that I could search for custom QuickLook plugins (or create one) but it'd be easier and good enough just to use the simple text viewer.

Comment: I installed QLStephen, which did successfully allow me to QuickLook my .org files. But it caused [other problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634440/on-osx-how-to-prevent-qlstephen-from-executing-sh-files).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the sample UTImportedTypeDeclarations from [qlcolorcode](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/), I use this entry:

```
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.source-code</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Org-mode Text</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>org.emacs.org-mode</string>
        <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
        <string>http://orgmode.org/</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>org</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Don't forget to run 'sudo qlmanage -r' from the Terminal(or relogin) to pick up the changes.

Comment: Worked, but I also had to `touch /Applications/TextEdit.app`

Comment: Where am I supposed to put this code?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to apply [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20100316063123/http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071028184428583) to adding the extension to TextEdit (rather than TexShop) to get what you want.

Good luck!

Comment: Tried this, didn't take.