# Make OS X's Quick Look work for custom file extensions

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

I find Finder's Quick Look feature (launched with <kbd>Space</kbd>) very useful, but it works only for a limited number of file extensions. In work I often get .properties, .conf, .ddl and other files which are essentially text, yet in Quick Look their content is never displayed:

[image]

Is there any way I can tell my Mac to treat those files as text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[QLStephen](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen) adds support for both files without a filename extension (like `README`) and files with arbitrary extensions (like `file.xyz`).

---

Quick Installation using Homebrew:

```bsh
brew install qlstephen
```

Manual Installation:

- Download [plugin](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/releases/download/1.4.3/QLStephen.qlgenerator.1.4.3.zip)
- Unzip
- Move file to ~/Library/QuickLook

*(Don't forget to `star` the [repo](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen) if this plugin helps you.)*

Comment: The way to do this is to add public.data to any quicklook generator's plist.  The downside is that binary files also do not have an extension and so it will try to display them, albiet usually with no negative consequences

Comment: @Brandon - it appears there is a directories blacklist in QLStephen which prevents files with no extensions from being shown if they are in the `bin` directory, also there is a whitelist which enables it for README and files of that sort which could work. I'm having trouble getting this to work on ML tho.

Comment: It's not the `bin` directory that blocks QLStephen; it's the executable file permissions.

Comment: What do I do once I install it? The README says `- Make sure you are editing (a) the correct plist of (b) the correct bundle. (For example, you might have two `QLStephen` plugins. It’s possible the plugin in another directory—perhaps `/Library/QuickLook/`—is what is being read.` but it doesn't say what plist I'm supposed to edit or what I'm supposed to add to that file.

Comment: Apparently QLStephen is now available on homebrew as `brew cask install qlstephen`

Comment: For those looking for additional Quick Look plugins, check out https://github.com/sindresorhus/quick-look-plugins for a good list with examples and instructions.


Or quick install: `brew cask install qlcolorcode qlstephen qlmarkdown quicklook-json qlimagesize suspicious-package quicklookase qlvideo`

Comment: I seem to recall having success with this in the past. However, I just tried it on Mojave 10.15.7 and it's not working for me.

Answer (score 13):

You might also want to have a look at the QLColorCode and QLMarkdown plugins, for syntax highlighting of many languages and markdown rendering respectively.

http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/

http://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/

_c

Answer (score 9):

A search for `quicklook` on github reveals that there is a large variety of extensions available:

- iPhone / iPad / iPod Touch application icons [quicklook-ipa](https://github.com/julienchauveau/quicklook-ipa)
- dot preview [quicklook-dot](https://github.com/besi/quicklook-dot)
- Display image dimensions in title bar [qlImageSize](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/qlImageSize)
- Viewing plain text file w/o extension [QuicklookStephen](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen)
- [MultiMarkdown QuickLook Plugin](https://github.com/fletcher/MMD-QuickLook)
- [EPUB QuickLook generator and Spotlight importer](https://github.com/jaketmp/ePub-quicklook)
- [Lightroom .lrcat](https://github.com/jarnoh/quicklook-lightroom)
- [Apple QuickLook Plugin for PPM, PGM, PFM and PBM files](https://github.com/lnxbil/quicklook-pfm)
- [CSV files](https://github.com/p2/quicklook-csv)
- [BetterZip overhaul](https://github.com/farfanoide/BetterZ-QuickLook-plugin-theme-for-Lion)
- [MATLAB .mat files](https://github.com/jaketmp/matlab-quicklook)
- [NFO](https://github.com/planbnet/QuickNFO) files
- [Hazel rule for Auto-Quicklook](https://github.com/robertcedwards/auto-quicklook)
- [Sublime Text 2](https://github.com/wallysalami/QuickLook)
- [Markdown as html](https://github.com/drewfranklin/markdown-quicklook)
- [PhotoCD (coverflow) files](https://github.com/sheepdoll/Quicklook_PCD)
- [Autopano Pro files](https://github.com/valgit/quicklook-autopano)
- [WebP thumbnails and previews](https://github.com/dchest/webp-quicklook)
- [Lytro's Light Field Picture files](https://github.com/maxvw/lytro-quicklook)
- [PowerVR .pvr files](https://github.com/Volcore/quickpvr)
- [JSON files](https://github.com/rjregenold/jsonlook)
- [Sony Mavica *.411](https://github.com/sheepdoll/quicklook_d411)
- [apparently custom QuickLook image suport](https://github.com/incbee/NSImage-QuickLook)
- [.hx files](https://github.com/KodeIn/QuickLook-HaXe-Plugin)
- [FITS files](https://github.com/onekiloparsec/QLFits)
- [QuickCHM files](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QuickCHM)
- [Adium Chatlogs](https://github.com/the-kenny/AdiumChatQuickLook)
- [SQLite3](https://github.com/macieks72/QLSqlite3)
- [DDS files](https://github.com/Marginal/QLdds)
- [markdown](https://github.com/mportiz08/qlmd)
- [.mdinfo files](https://github.com/echoz/QLMDInfo)
- [sublime-snippet and tmSnippet](https://github.com/hetima/SublimeSnippetQL)
- [outdated zip](https://github.com/ndrake/ZipQuickLook)
- [ePub cover pages](https://github.com/Crazor/QuickPub)
- [Haskell syntax highlighting](https://github.com/atomb/hsquicklook)
- [Drupal filetypes](https://github.com/BrianGilbert/QLColorCode-extra) and more (module, profile, theme, install, inc)
- [Creating thumbnails via OS X QuickLook](https://github.com/mrdougal/clipper)
- [r0ket .lcd files](https://github.com/monkeydom/r0ketlcdql)
- [audio files](https://github.com/farski/AudioAudit)
- [PDB files](https://github.com/BenPorebski/QuickLookPDB)
- [crippled iPhone png files](https://github.com/0xced/crippng)
- [diffraction image data](https://github.com/BenPorebski/QuickLookDiffract)
- [FIT files from Garmin devices and such](https://github.com/dbr/QLfit)
- [PES Embroidery Files](https://github.com/sabberworm/PES-QLGenerator)
- [FictionBook (fb2) e-book files](https://github.com/gonzoua/FictionBook2QL)
- [Markdown](https://github.com/qvacua/lookdown)
- [Adium Chat Log](https://github.com/luk-/AdiumChatQuickLook)
- [Windows BMP files](https://github.com/hirobe/bmpQuickLook)
- [Go source files](https://github.com/chauvd/GoQL)
- [Cocoa sqlite database files](https://github.com/chuthan20/sqlitebrowser)
- [source coloring](https://github.com/nacho4d/SourceSpectrum)
- [WebP image files](https://github.com/emin/WebPQuickLook)
- [Netpbm files (.PBM, .PGM, .PPM, .PAM)](https://github.com/AntonDukhovnikov/PAMQuickLookPlugIn)
- [Dart source files](https://github.com/chauvd/DartQL)
- [OSGi bundles](https://github.com/milgner/qlosgi)
- [Agilent/Varian FDF formats](https://github.com/andrewcurtis/QLPluginFDF)
- [For files that are commonly found in structural biology](https://github.com/BenPorebski/CrystallographyQLPlugins)
- [JSON, supporting fold/unfold sub-tress](https://github.com/johan/QuickJSON)
- [iCloud CDT files](https://github.com/chbeer/QuickLookiCloudCDTPlugin): see deletes, inserts and updates
- [Markdown-Viewer](https://github.com/MichaelSeeberger/Markdown-Viewer), a viewer which provides QuickLook support as well,

and some (incomplete) collections:

- [QuickLook 1](https://github.com/delynn/QuickLook)
- [QuickLook 2](https://github.com/crymer11/QuickLook)

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/363915/how-can-i-view-indesign-incopy-quarkxpress-etc-documents-without-opening-them, http://superuser.com/questions/275839/how-do-i-make-powerpoint-files-open-with-quick-look-by-default-on-mac-os-x/275844#275844, http://superuser.com/questions/113410/use-text-quicklook-viewer-for-other-files, http://superuser.com/questions/472317/extend-capabilities-of-finders-quick-view/472325#472325, http://superuser.com/questions/248013/is-it-possible-to-set-a-custom-quick-look-preview-image-in-os-x/252503#252503

Comment: and also: http://superuser.com/questions/171323/how-to-make-quick-look-preview-text-files-in-utf-8-by-default/171337#171337, http://superuser.com/questions/171323/how-to-make-quick-look-preview-text-files-in-utf-8-by-default/171415#171415

Comment: None of those extensions or 'related' questions, as far as I can tell, answer the question I asked.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible, but not really easy.

If you look at `/System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist`, you'll notice that the "text" preview is for the following [UTIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier):

```
public.plain-text
public.rtf
com.apple.rtfd
org.oasis-open.opendocument.text
com.apple.property-list
public.xml
```

This is how QuickLook knows which Plugin (`qlgenerator`) to use.

---

A (hackish) solution now would be to assign the extension `properties` the UTI `public.plain-text`. To do this, you could create a dummy application (e.g. created by Automator) that declares these file types like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353851/assigning-uti-to-file-type), only you'd use `public.plain-text` as UTI and `properties` as file extension.

Comment: In the end, I've added custom file types to existing text editor (TextWrangler). Works fine, thanks!

Comment: @Nikita It's easier, but be aware that any TextWrangler update will nuke your changes to `Info.plist`.

Comment: I want to add a couple of extensions (.scala, .clj, .properties), what should I do?

Comment: @4bu3li Do what I wrote in my answer and it'll work, I just did it yesterday the same way. Or do you just require a more detailed explanation?

Comment: I would like i more detailed explanation. Can't i not just add public.pde for example in the plist?

Answer (score 3):

A solution for 2021...

QLColorCode is an alternative to QLStephen. I have used them both over the years but have had more success with the former. My use case is being able to read `my-example.Dockerfile` but you should be able to adapt to what you need.

First, let's install QLColorCode:

```
>brew install qlcolorcode
```

Now get the metadata name that MacOS uses for your file. To do this we use the `mdls` command from the Terminal and call it on the path to an example of the filetype you want to configure quicklook for.

```
>mdls -name kMDItemContentType ~/Documents/my-example.Dockerfile
```

For me this outputs:

```
kMDItemContentType = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80k55drrw1e3xmrvwu"
```

Copy the part in quotes as you will need this in a moment. Open the Info.plist for QLColorCode in your favourite text editor. I like vim.

```
>vim ~/Library/QuickLook/QLColorCode.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist
```

Navigate down to the part that looks like this:

```
                    <array>
                            <string>public.source-code</string>
                            <string>public.yaml</string>
                            <string>com.apple.xcode.tcsh-script</string>
[...and so on...]
                    </array>
```

Insert a new element with your copied ContentType code. It should look something like this now:

```
                    <array>
                            <string>public.source-code</string>
                            <string>public.yaml</string>
                            <string>com.apple.xcode.tcsh-script</string>
[...and so on...]
                            <string>dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80k55drrw1e3xmrvwu</string>
                    </array>
```

Save your file and relaunch Finder. To restart Finder, click on the Apple icon (top left of screen), select "Force Quit..." and then select Finder. Hit "Relaunch".

Now, when you select a `*.Dockerfile` in Finder and hit spacebar, you should see the content

Comment: Thanks to the user that pointed out missing "kMDItemContentType" in the mdls command.