# Is it possible to set a Custom quick look preview image in OS X?

Tags: shell, applescript

Is there any way to set a custom quick look image in OS X?
I'd like a command line tool or applescript to change or embed a custom preview for a zip file using a jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how QuickLook works.  Quicklook has processes that run in the background to interrogate a file for its filetype, then look for a generator for that file type and the generator returns either HTML-based or image-based content.

There are programs that will show a listing of files inside a Zip (or other archive files) but you can't "embed" a preview image for Quick Look, at least AFAIK.