# How can i view InDesign, InCopy, QuarkXPress etc. documents without opening them in their applications?

Tags: preview, viewer, quicklook

i am looking for a solution, software, plug-in, application or so which allows me to view/preview InDesign, InCopy, QuarkXPress documents etc. on Mac in QuickLook. It should be a smart, with some basic or more options or so and most importantly an economical solution which i can afford. As i can't or say don't want to spend that much money to buy licenses for InDesign or other applications.
My work also include to move these documents on different systems (Mac or Windows). So installing such software and then uninstalling them is huge time wastage. I want a plug-in or so which get install/Uninstall in a faction of second. So that i'll be able to install it on other system, show my work and then remove it from there in a minute or so.

Hope and will appreciate to have your immediate & kind attention/suggestion/recommendations on my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following software product (ADOView), it would allow you to preview your InDesign, QuarkXPress, Illustrator Documents on both MAC and PC. It also works with IDML Files.

http://www.metadesignsolutions.com/products/indesign-viewer.php