# Extend capabilities of Finder's quick view

Tags: macos, finder, file-types

When you have selected a text, source, html file, etc., in Finder and press spacebar, a quick view will come up showing content. When the file extension isn't one that is recognized, it will instead show information like name, extension, file size..  How do I edit how it responds to different file types? Can I make it show content for binary files as if they are text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Quick Look plugins by moving them to ~/Library/QuickLook/.

[QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.com/qlstephen/) adds support for plain text files with arbitrary extensions or without an extension. It also supports some binary formats and executable scripts, but not compiled binaries.

[qlcolorcode](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/) adds syntax highlighting for source code files.

Comment: You can now install QLStephen and more with brew - see https://github.com/sindresorhus/quick-look-plugins for a good list with examples and instructions. Or quick install: `brew cask install qlcolorcode qlstephen qlmarkdown quicklook-json qlimagesize suspicious-package quicklookase qlvideo`